# SQL fetch only single record out of multiple matching the numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2
Consider two Columns named ID and ID1 with the below values.

```
   ID         ¦ ID1
--------------¦-------
   A100       ¦ 101
   B100       ¦ 102
   OB100      ¦ 103
   D100A      ¦ 104
   Z100A      ¦ 105
```

Task is to retrieve only one of the rows , so logic is like if numeric digits match (eg. 100) fetch only one of them where the other column (ID1) value is Max.

For the above data, The query will return Z100A because that has max ID1 value and ignore other rows in result.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used. Also, show some sample data from the other column and the expected result.

Comment: Max of what?  What other column value?  You're only showing one.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Consider a Column named ID with the above values A100,B100,OB100,D100A,Z100A and other column ID1 with values 101,102,103,104,105 . Fetch Z100A coz that has max ID1 value and ignore other rows in result. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What's the format of `ID` column? Is something like `xNx`, where x is a word and N is an integer number?

Answer (score 0):

First, create following function. This function gets a `VARCHAR` which contains a number in it(eg. `Z100A`) then returns the integer number in it(eg. `100`).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNumeric(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT

    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
        END
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

Then you need to execute following `SELECT` query to get the result.

Note that the `WHERE` section is commented. If you want uncomment it to force more restriction:

```
SELECT  dbo.GetNumeric(ID) AS ID_Num, MAX(ID1) AS Max_ID1
FROM    MyIdTable
--WHERE dbo.GetNumeric(ID) = 100
GROUP   BY dbo.GetNumeric(ID)
```

If you want to get actual `ID` name like `Z100A`, use following `SELECT` query:

Note: Fetched Number in `ID` is commented, but if you want to have it in the result of query you can uncomment it.

```
SELECT  MAX(ID)              AS ID,
        --dbo.GetNumeric(ID) AS ID_Num,
        MAX(ID1)             AS Max_ID1
FROM    MyIdTable
--WHERE dbo.GetNumeric(ID) = 100
GROUP   BY dbo.GetNumeric(ID)
```

Comment: The above code is fetching data but doesn't get the actual ID name like 'Z100A' instead we only get '100'. If I include the actual column in select list it again gives me multiple records.

Comment: @Minti, A new update is posted. This is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the above code, This logic works, but when I am tryng to nclude multiple fields in select statement , SQL propmts "Column XYZ" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. How should I proceed , should I use max for all columns used will it provide the right result..I am not sure

Comment: @Minti, Let me know which `SELECT` statement do you use?

Comment: My select statement uses other columns from the table,  I cannot share my query on web.

Comment: OK, In this case you need to have a primary key to have which columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @n nvarchar(10) = '100'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('A100', 101),
('B100', 102),
('OB100', 103),
('D100A', 104),
('Z100A', 105)
) as t(ID, ID1)
)

SELECT c.ID 
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID1) as ID1
    FROM cte
    WHERE ID LIKE '%'+@n+'%'
    ) as t 
        ON t.ID1 = c.ID1
```

Output:

```
ID
-----
Z100A

(1 row(s) affected)
```