# SQL Server : grouping on partial text matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I have a table like:

```
Name                            Size
--------------------------------------    
backup_20160426000000.comp.trn  1
backup_20160426001000.comp.trn  2
backup_20160426002000.comp.trn  4
(..)
backup_20160426230000.comp.trn  4
backup_20160426231000.comp.trn  5
```

I need to be able to GROUP the text BY "hour" (20160426000000 would be Hour 0, 20160426010000 would be hour 1, etc..) and then sum up the total size.

Output should be:

```
backup_20160426000000.comp.trn  7
(..)
backup_20160426230000.comp.trn  9
```

Currently I have:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(dbo.CLName.NAME, PATINDEX('%2016%', dbo.CLName.NAME), 14), size
FROM 
    dbo.CLName
GROUP BY 
    substring(Name, 1, 15)
```

Comment: What are the results being returned? Will you please add that?

Comment: You must use `GROUP BY', but which `Name` in group should be returned as result?

Comment: Select either has to be the group by or an aggregate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the strings have the same format, you could just take them appart and reconstruct them using `substring`, as you have partially done:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, 15) + '0000.comp.trn', SUM(size)
FROM 
    dbo.CLName
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, 15)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, though I prefer to use `Left()` and `Right()` instead of `Substring()` if I'm not taking a section of string from the middle - otherwise the intent is misleading.  This also assumes the extensions ".comp.trn" will always be the same, but since the author didn't specify they could be different, this answer is still valid.

Comment: This will not work if the strings are not all the same format just as you mentioned: ex backup1_20160426000000, backup23_20160426000000, backup567_20160426000000. Any idea for this case?

Comment: forget it , easy fix, just changing "15" to something like SUBSTRING(name, 1, DATALENGTH(name)-13) since the end part of the text is always the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Mureinik, simples and most effective answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING` function to get the hour.

```
SELECT  MIN(Name) AS Name, SUM(Size) AS Size_Sum
FROM    TblBackup
GROUP   BY SUBSTRING(Name, 16, 2)
```

Output Result:

```
Name                              Size_Sum
--------------------------------------------
backup_20160426000000.comp.trn       7
backup_20160426230000.comp.trn       9
```

Comment: Agree that matches the existing data but I doubt this meets the actual requirement.

Comment: This also will not work when the name of the entries differ in size length ex: backup1_20160426000000, backup23_20160426000000, backup567_20160426000000

Comment: Yes you're right, but we supposed the mentioned format for backup naming. To get your supposed format, follow post [SQL fetch only single record out of multiple matching the numeric values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36988864/3472827)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed field to the table to derive the date and time, like this. (Note: I've set the minutes to zero, assuming you are only interested in whole hours, but this could be changed.)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyBackup
(
    BackupName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Size int NOT NULL,
    BackupDateTime AS CAST(SUBSTRING(BackupName, 8, 4) + N'-' + SUBSTRING(BackupName, 12, 2) + N'-' + SUBSTRING(BackupName, 14, 2) + N' ' + SUBSTRING(BackupName, 16, 2) + N':00' AS datetime2(0))
);
GO
```

Then add the sample data.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyBackup (BackupName, Size)
    VALUES (N'backup_20160426000000.comp.trn', 1),
        (N'backup_20160426001000.comp.trn', 2),
        (N'backup_20160426002000.comp.trn', 4),
        (N'backup_20160426230000.comp.trn', 4),
        (N'backup_20160426231000.comp.trn', 5);
```

Then you can select and group by the BackupDateTime and sum the Size.

```
SELECT BackupDateTime, SUM(Size) AS 'Size'
    FROM dbo.MyBackup
    GROUP BY BackupDateTime
    ORDER BY BackupDateTime;
```

[image]

Or to display it exactly as you showed.

```
SELECT N'backup_' + FORMAT(YEAR(BackupDateTime), '0000') + FORMAT(MONTH(BackupDateTime), '00') + FORMAT(DAY(BackupDateTime), '00') + FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, BackupDateTime), '00') + FORMAT(DATEPART(minute, BackupDateTime), '00') + N'00.comp.trn' AS 'Name', SUM(Size) AS 'Size'
    FROM dbo.MyBackup
    GROUP BY BackupDateTime
    ORDER BY BackupDateTime;
```

[image]